# How to hear audio in Android using SIP?

Tags: android, audio, sip, android-music-player

> I'm trying to develop an Android app with calling capabilities using sip and freeswitch. I'm able to register a profile successfully and also, able to make a call to freeswitch's test IVR profile. However, I'm unable to hear any audio.
>
> Below is a snippet of my manifest containing all the permissions and features

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
```

> Below is the snippet of my SipAudioCall.Listener

```
listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCalling(SipAudioCall call) {
                        //super.onCalling(call);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Initiating session!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                        //super.onCallEstablished(call);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Call started!");
                        call.startAudio();
                        call.setSpeakerMode(true);

                        if (call.isMuted()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Muted");
                            call.toggleMute();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
                        //super.onRinging(call, caller);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Ringing!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRingingBack(SipAudioCall call) {
                        //super.onRingingBack(call);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Ringing back");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                        //super.onCallEnded(call);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Call ended");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(SipAudioCall call, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                        //super.onError(call, errorCode, errorMessage);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error! " + errorMessage);
                    }
                };


                call = sipManager.makeAudioCall(sipProfile.getUriString(), "sip:5000@192.168.0.6", listener, 30);
```

Comment: Most android and iOS users use pjsip as a SIP lib to communicate over VOIP servers. I guess you should be using same. Please register a user from desktop sip client like zoiper,xlite,jitis etc. Make a call and make sure your server doesn't have any NAT issues and then start to track down on your android device. Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436703/no-audio-using-native-android-sip-library?rq=1 which looks similar

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
@Override
public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
   //super.onCallEstablished(call);
   Log.d(TAG, "Call started!");
   call.setSpeakerMode(true);
   call.startAudio();
}
```

instead of

```
@Override
public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
   //super.onCallEstablished(call);
   Log.d(TAG, "Call started!");
   call.startAudio();
   call.setSpeakerMode(true);
   if (call.isMuted()) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Muted");
       call.toggleMute();
   }

}
```

Comment: No luck! As far as I know, SIP standard does not address passing audio and video data over a network. One needs to implement a codec to receive the audio. However, I don't know exactly how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Check below points to solve this problem:

- First check your network is behind NAT or not then use extern SIP IP and RTP IP as your live IP
- check whether you have installed codec successfully (gsm, g729, pcma, pcmu)
- check for gateway capability

So first check that on sip softphone, then go to Android.